# How can I make this CSS only text slider responsive

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a way to make this HTML and CSS slider responsive, the text just disappears however when I set it to overflow-x:hidden it just adds a scroll.

I've tried for a day experimenting with different height and states, any help would be greatly appreciated

If possible it would be great if any help was CSS tweeks as I'm trying to avoid Javascript for this project, thanks
HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pure CSS3 Overlapping Content Slideshow</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin:400,600" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div class="css-slider">
<input id="slide-1" type="radio" name="slides" checked>
<section class="slide slide-one">
<div class="slideText">
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a turpis sit amet tortor egestas convallis. Pellentesque pharetra, lectus sit amet pulvinar vestibulum</span></p>

<p>sem tortor tincidunt diam, vel pretium velit est vitae dolor. Sed vitae orci ac nisi consequat sollicitudin. Donec id feugiat est, non aliquet ex. Ut a tortor imperdiet, feugiat nisl in, venenatis eros. Aenean sed ullamcorper massa, sit amet ullamcorper leo. Nulla non ante at enim consequat venenatis ut in tellus.</p>
    </div>
  <nav>


    <label for="slide-3" class="prev">&#10094;</label>
    <label for="slide-2" class="next">&#10095;</label>
  </nav>
</section>
<input id="slide-2" type="radio" name="slides">
<section class="slide slide-two">
  <div class="slideText">
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a turpis sit amet tortor egestas convallis. Pellentesque pharetra, lectus sit amet pulvinar vestibulum</span></p>

<p>sem tortor tincidunt diam, vel pretium velit est vitae dolor. Sed vitae orci ac nisi consequat sollicitudin. Donec id feugiat est, non aliquet ex. Ut a tortor imperdiet, feugiat nisl in, venenatis eros. Aenean sed ullamcorper massa, sit amet ullamcorper leo. Nulla non ante at enim consequat venenatis ut in tellus.</p>
    </div>
  <nav>
    <label for="slide-1" class="prev">&#10094;</label>
    <label for="slide-3" class="next">&#10095;</label>
  </nav>
</section>
<input id="slide-3" type="radio" name="slides">
<section class="slide slide-three">
  <div class="slideText">
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a turpis sit amet tortor egestas convallis. Pellentesque pharetra, lectus sit amet pulvinar vestibulum</span></p>

<p>sem tortor tincidunt diam, vel pretium velit est vitae dolor. Sed vitae orci ac nisi consequat sollicitudin. Donec id feugiat est, non aliquet ex. Ut a tortor imperdiet, feugiat nisl in, venenatis eros. Aenean sed ullamcorper massa, sit amet ullamcorper leo. Nulla non ante at enim consequat venenatis ut in tellus. </p>
    </div>
  <nav>
    <label for="slide-2" class="prev">&#10094;</label>
    <label for="slide-1" class="next">&#10095;</label>
  </nav>
</section>
<header>
  <label for="slide-1" id="slide-1"></label>
  <label for="slide-2" id="slide-2"></label>
  <label for="slide-3" id="slide-3"></label>
</header>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;


font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;


}

*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }

h1 {
color: #fff;
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 1.2;
margin: 0.5em 0 3em;
}

.css-slider {
min-height: 450px;
max-width: 980px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
background: #2d2926;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}
.css-slider span {
color: #89cb31;
font-style: italic;
}

label {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
}

header {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 900;
width: 100%;
}

header label {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
border-radius: 50%;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
margin: 20px 10px;
}

nav {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -42px;
z-index: 900;
width: 100%;
}

nav label { font-size: 50px; }

header label:hover { background: #89cb31; }

.prev {
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
}

.next {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
}

.slide {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1920px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
z-index: 10;
padding: 2em 0px;
background-color: #2d2926;
background-position: 150% -500%;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-transition: left 0s .75s ease-in-out;
transition: left 0s .75s ease-in-out;


}
.slideText {
padding: 0 5em;
}

.slide .prev, .slide .next { opacity: 0; }

input#slide-1:checked ~ header label#slide-1, input#slide-2:checked ~ header label#slide-2, input#slide-3:checked ~ header label#slide-3 { background: #89cb31; }

[id^="slide"]:checked + .slide {
left: 0;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-transition: left .65s ease-in-out;
transition: left .65s ease-in-out;
}

[id^="slide"]:checked + .slide h1 {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
-ms-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
-webkit-transition: all .5s .5s;
transition: all .5s .5s;
}

[id^="slide"]:checked + .slide .prev, [id^="slide"]:checked + .slide .next {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all .5s .5s;
transition: all .5s .5s;
}
```

Comment: If not making the text disappear or adding a scroll bar, what effect do you want to have happen?

Comment: If possible the sliders height adjusting depending on how much text there is

Comment: Have you tried removing the hardcoded `max-height` from it?

Comment: max-height from what? I dont see any in the css